# For given string - which encoding type does it have?

Tags: encoding

This string:

```
UEsDBC0AAAAIAONzTkAiH3jE//////////8XABQAV2luZG93c0FwcGxpY2F0aW9uNzAuZWwBABAAEM0AAAAAAABjHQA
AAAAAAO1dbW/buJb+PsD8BwILLFrc1uWbSMmfNk3cNnuTNBunnblYLwJZlhPd2pZXkpPmQr9pf+MekpL8JjuWYnk8wLAtko
qkePTo8PDh4SHVmUX+D/civEeiZbUI/fWXX385mU5HgecmQThp//rL+z2kX39BiLQI6iZulKAzN/GRTm10O/PfIcLRJ7
+PKCYUEdamom056G+YYGwqUnTljv0PZ37sRcFUy4V+CyaD8ClekFXi1mP8EMZJy//pozfz39+auzD03Y9iKIiuZuO+H6nm7
Rbm+e+89ZI1IdH6G0OJdHMKzFmx4abNJspBHTIajlDGZxfOMK/8pww6jqzBZfFvqxXyL/Wi
```

Which Encoding type does it have? I have a zip file which I need to convert to that format, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @JuicyScripter: Please post your answer as an answer so it can be up voted properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [`base64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded zip archive (at least part of).

Comment: Isn't base64 actually byte[], and byte[] is [34][56]..[89]?

Comment: @Srcee: base64 is a way to encode 8bit data over a channel which doesn't support 8bit data (say ASCII text transfer which doesn't allow bytes 128-255). This has nothing to do with `byte[]`.